# Conceptual Clarity on frameCount and rotate function in p5.js

Tags: processing, computational-geometry, p5.js

I was doing one of the examples on the p5.js website - https://p5js.org/examples/form-regular-polygon.html. I got really confused by the way rotate function worked in that code . IN the below function if I just pass rotate(frameCount) , in the browser it shows me rotating two triangles intersected within forming a star , but as soon as I divide the frameCount it disappears. Also the equation used in the code - can some one give the mathematical intuition on how we reached to this point.

```
let sx = x + cos(a) * radius;
let sy = y + sin(a) * radius;
```

```
 push();
 translate(width * 0.2, height * 0.5);
 rotate(frameCount / 50);
 polygon(0,0,82,3);
 pop();
```

Comment: Also discussed there --> https://discourse.processing.org/t/conceptual-clarity-on-framecount-and-rotate-function/22246/3 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding "two triangles intersected within forming a star":

By default, the `rotate` function takes radians. When you do `rotate(frameCount)`, you are increasing the angle by 1 radian at each frame. One radian equals about 57 degrees, so your triangle would rotate about 57 degrees at each frame. At frame 3, the triangle would have rotated about 120 degrees, and it would roughly overlap with the triangle at frame 1. Similarly, the triangle at frame 4 would roughly overlap with the triangle at frame 2.

The "two triangles" you are seeing is just two groups of triangles, one group being triangles at frame 1, 3, 5... and another group being triangles at frame 2, 4, 6...

That is why you should divide `frameCount` by some number if you would like to obtain a rather continuous rotation. Alternatively, you could also set [angleMode](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/angleMode) to `DEGREES`. In that case, you don't have to divide `frameCount` anymore because at each frame the triangle would only rotate 1 degree instead of 1 radian.

Regarding the math formula:

In fact, the function used in that example should be called `regularPolygon` instead of `polygon` because it only draws regular polygons.

Now, how do you draw a regular polygon? You know the distance from each vertex to the center is a constant number. In this example, that number is the `radius` variable. And you know if you use polar coordinates with the center of the polygon as the origin point, the angle difference between every two adjacent vertices is also a constant number. In this example, that number is the `angle` variable.

More precisely, the polar coordinates of the vertices should take the form of:

```
v1 = (radius, 0)
v2 = (radius, angle)
v3 = (radius, angle*2)
...
```

Convert them to cartesian coordinates, you would obtain something like:

```
v1 = (cos(0)       * radius, sin(0)       * radius)
v2 = (cos(angle)   * radius, sin(angle)   * radius)
v3 = (cos(angle*2) * radius, sin(angle*2) * radius)
...
```

But what if the center of the polygon is not the origin point, but point `(x, y)`, as in the example? Now the cartesian coordinates of the vertices become:

```
v1 = (x + cos(0)       * radius, y + sin(0)       * radius)
v2 = (x + cos(angle)   * radius, y + sin(angle)   * radius)
v3 = (x + cos(angle*2) * radius, y + sin(angle*2) * radius)
```

So when you do:

```
for (let a = 0; a < TWO_PI; a += angle) {
    let sx = x + cos(a) * radius;
    let sy = y + sin(a) * radius;
    vertex(sx, sy);
  }
```

You are really drawing the vertices `v1, v2, v3...`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation though I have one doubt - for instance i just want to create the triangle with parameters polygon(360,200,82,3); Now and I comment everything from the code. Just the plygon function should create the triangle with these parameters. And when i run a triangle gets created at the center of the canvas. Please let me know if my understanding is correct, the origin (360,200) is at the center of the triangle and from there at angle 0 degree first vertex is calculated , then adding 120 degrees second vertex and then adding 240 degrees third vertex. Is it correct?

Comment: @isilia Your welcome :) And please don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question. As for the new question: yes, your understanding is correct.

Comment: Just one last doubt if you can shed some light on it - When you mentioned - v1 = (radius, 0) , the angle is taken as 0 degree but is that a necessary condition for the first vertex or I can take some other angle than 0 degree. My understanding of polar coordinates is bit weak so excuse me if my question sounds stupid. If we can take angle other than 0 degree , what would be the equations then for v1,v2 and v3 ?

Comment: I noticed one more thing - translate(width * 0.2, height * 0.5);
 polygon(0,0,82,3);
 rotate(frameCount / 200); . If I edit the code like this then it will create the triangle but will not rotate it. Why is that. I mean if I put the polygon function at the end only then the polygon starts rotating. Why is sequence important here in this , ideally first the origin is shifted , then polygon is constructed and then rotate function should rotate the polygon but thats not the case. Please help me clear this confusion as well